# How to avoid images with spanned fromHtml?

Tags: java, android, spanned

i m getting blank images using spanned from.Html.
Is there any way to hide them and get only text?

```
 Spanned description = Html.fromHtml(des.get(position));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Html.fromHtml(String source)`, you can use `Html.fromHtml(String source, Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler)`.

Implement an `ImageGetter` that returns a blank image, and pass `null` for the `TagHandler`.